# Positioning of CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently trying to implement a `CAShapeLayer`. It works fine, but its position isn't working the way I want it to.

I want the circle to be displayed inside of the top selected UIView you see in the second image below. To do that, I tried to set `arcCenter` to `circleView.center`. But what's being displayed is the image below.

**How it's being displayed:**
[image]

**I want it to be displayed in the center inside of this UIView:**
[image]

**My code:**

```
func displayCircle() {
        let color = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 95/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1)
        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let center = circleView.center
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 20
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 20
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0

        circleView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        circleView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
```

**Edit, UIView's constraints:**
[image]

Comment: Where do you call `displayCircle` from? Is `circleView` properly constrained using auto layout?

Comment: @luk2302 It's being called in `viewDidLoad()`. `circleView`'s constraints are created with the storyboard (see edit).

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is too early, the view has not been layed out yet. Use `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks, now it's being displayed a little more to the top, but on the right - still not in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change your center position of circle view like below,

```
let center = CGPoint(x: circleView.frame.size.width/2, y: circleView.frame.size.height/2)
```

Hope this way may help you.